# arm-hisiv300-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I just changed the CMakeLists.txt by adding:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-hisiv300-linux/target/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-hisiv300-linux/target/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-g++)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-hisiv300-linux/)
```

Unluckly,I got a problem:

```
root@lzw-virtual-machine:/home/lzw/OpenFace/OpenFace/build# make
Scanning dependencies of target dlib
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/3rdParty/dlib/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/include/dlib/base64/base64_kernel_1.o
arm-hisiv300-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
arm-hisiv300-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
arm-hisiv300-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse3’
```

Comment: `I just changed the CMakeLists.txt by adding...` - things like *CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME* should be set **only** in [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Preferred place for *CMAKE_C_COMPILER*, *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* an so is toolchain file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all options enabling various generations of the x86 instruction set extensions for the SSE SIMD processing unit; they don't exist on ARM so they are not going to work ...

Check your build system is able to distinguish based on CPU architecture ...